# Sliding Block Puzzle

Tags: sliding-blocks

I am working on these Klotski puzzles which are really hard to solve, and I got stuck at this one:

[image: The puzzle]

It tells me that the puzzle can be solved in 46 moves. I could show my progress, but since most people who help to solve them will use code, I do not think that that will be necessary. Thanks for helping, this might not be the last one I will ask for.

The dark brown block is not moveable and the red one has to be where the red dots are.

Comment: Where does it come from ? My computer program couldn't solve it ; can we move the 1x1 piece on row 6 col 3 ?

Comment: @classicalMpk It is an App called Klotski. Set 2 Level 31. And the brown block is not moveable.

Comment: I make it 102 moves where each move is moving a block by one cell.

Comment: The color choice makes difficult to tell which are the blocks, which is the floor and that the central square at the bottom is actually a brown block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full solution in 46 moves:

> ```
>  0
>  . a a a .
>  . a c a .
>  . . c . .
>  b b c d d
>  e b g d f
>  e h x i f
>  
>  1
>  . a a a .
>  . a c a .
>  b b c . .
>  . b c d d
>  e . g d f
>  e h x i f
>  
>  2
>  . a a a .
>  . a c a .
>  b b c . .
>  . b c d d
>  e g . d f
>  e h x i f
>  
>  3
>  . a a a .
>  . a . a .
>  b b c . .
>  . b c d d
>  e g c d f
>  e h x i f
>  
>  4
>  a a a . .
>  a . a . .
>  b b c . .
>  . b c d d
>  e g c d f
>  e h x i f
>  
>  5
>  a a a d d
>  a . a d .
>  b b c . .
>  . b c . .
>  e g c . f
>  e h x i f
>  
>  6
>  a a a d d
>  a . a d i
>  b b c . .
>  . b c . .
>  e g c . f
>  e h x . f
>  
>  7
>  a a a d d
>  a . a d i
>  b b . . .
>  . b . c .
>  e g . c f
>  e h x c f
>  
>  8
>  a a a d d
>  a . a d .
>  b b . i .
>  . b . c .
>  e g . c f
>  e h x c f
>  
>  9
>  a a a d d
>  a . a d f
>  b b . i f
>  . b . c .
>  e g . c .
>  e h x c .
>  
>  10
>  a a a d d
>  a . a d f
>  b b . i f
>  . b . . c
>  e g . . c
>  e h x . c
>  
>  11
>  a a a d d
>  a . a d f
>  . . . i f
>  . . b b c
>  e g . b c
>  e h x . c
>  
>  12
>  a a a d d
>  a e a d f
>  . e . i f
>  . . b b c
>  . g . b c
>  . h x . c
>  
>  13
>  a a a d d
>  a e a d f
>  g e . i f
>  . . b b c
>  . . . b c
>  . h x . c
>  
>  14
>  a a a d d
>  a e a d f
>  g e . i f
>  . . b b c
>  . . . b c
>  h . x . c
>  
>  15
>  a a a d d
>  a e a d f
>  g e . i f
>  . . . . c
>  b b . . c
>  h b x . c
>  
>  16
>  a a a d d
>  a . a d f
>  g . . i f
>  . . . . c
>  b b . e c
>  h b x e c
>  
>  17
>  a a a d d
>  a . a d f
>  . . . i f
>  . g . . c
>  b b . e c
>  h b x e c
>  
>  18
>  a a a d d
>  a . a d f
>  . . . . f
>  . g . . c
>  b b i e c
>  h b x e c
>  
>  19
>  . . . d d
>  . . . d f
>  a a a . f
>  a g a . c
>  b b i e c
>  h b x e c
>  
>  20
>  . . d d .
>  . . d . f
>  a a a . f
>  a g a . c
>  b b i e c
>  h b x e c
>  
>  21
>  . . d d .
>  . . d . .
>  a a a f .
>  a g a f c
>  b b i e c
>  h b x e c
>  
>  22
>  . . . d d
>  . . . d .
>  a a a f .
>  a g a f c
>  b b i e c
>  h b x e c
>  
>  23
>  a a a d d
>  a . a d .
>  . . . f .
>  . g . f c
>  b b i e c
>  h b x e c
>  
>  24
>  a a a d d
>  a . a d .
>  g . . f .
>  . . . f c
>  b b i e c
>  h b x e c
>  
>  25
>  a a a d d
>  a f a d .
>  g f . . .
>  . . . . c
>  b b i e c
>  h b x e c
>  
>  26
>  a a a d d
>  a f a d .
>  g f i . .
>  . . . . c
>  b b . e c
>  h b x e c
>  
>  27
>  a a a d d
>  a f a d c
>  g f i . c
>  . . . . c
>  b b . e .
>  h b x e .
>  
>  28
>  a a a d d
>  a f a d c
>  g f i . c
>  . . . . c
>  b b . . e
>  h b x . e
>  
>  29
>  a a a d d
>  a f a d c
>  g f i . c
>  . . . . c
>  . . b b e
>  h . x b e
>  
>  30
>  a a a d d
>  a f a d c
>  g f . . c
>  . . . . c
>  . . b b e
>  h i x b e
>  
>  31
>  a a a d d
>  a . a d c
>  g . . f c
>  . . . f c
>  . . b b e
>  h i x b e
>  
>  32
>  a a a d d
>  a . a d c
>  . . . f c
>  . . . f c
>  g . b b e
>  h i x b e
>  
>  33
>  . . . d d
>  . . . d c
>  a a a f c
>  a . a f c
>  g . b b e
>  h i x b e
>  
>  34
>  d d . . .
>  d . . . c
>  a a a f c
>  a . a f c
>  g . b b e
>  h i x b e
>  
>  35
>  d d f . .
>  d . f . c
>  a a a . c
>  a . a . c
>  g . b b e
>  h i x b e
>  
>  36
>  d d f c .
>  d . f c .
>  a a a c .
>  a . a . .
>  g . b b e
>  h i x b e
>  
>  37
>  d d f c e
>  d . f c e
>  a a a c .
>  a . a . .
>  g . b b .
>  h i x b .
>  
>  38
>  d d f c e
>  d . f c e
>  a a a c .
>  a . a b b
>  g . . . b
>  h i x . .
>  
>  39
>  d d f c e
>  d . f c e
>  a a a c .
>  a . a b b
>  . . . . b
>  h i x . g
>  
>  40
>  d d f c e
>  d . f c e
>  a a a c .
>  a . a b b
>  . . . . b
>  h . x i g
>  
>  41
>  d d f c e
>  d . f c e
>  . . . c .
>  a a a b b
>  a . a . b
>  h . x i g
>  
>  42
>  d d . c e
>  d f . c e
>  . f . c .
>  a a a b b
>  a . a . b
>  h . x i g
>  
>  43
>  d d c . e
>  d f c . e
>  . f c . .
>  a a a b b
>  a . a . b
>  h . x i g
>  
>  44
>  d d c . e
>  d f c . e
>  . f c b b
>  a a a . b
>  a . a . .
>  h . x i g
>  
>  45
>  d d c . e
>  d f c . e
>  . f c b b
>  a a a . b
>  a . a . i
>  h . x . g
>  
>  46
>  d d c . e
>  d f c . e
>  . f c b b
>  . . . . b
>  . a a a i
>  h a x a g
> ```

Comment: Ok thank you, I have reached this position, only not in 16 moves. Would be nice if you'll provide the whole step by step solution. :))

Comment: @calculatormathematical Full solution now.

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: @calculatormathematical I solved this manually, within the app.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution (computer assisted) in 102 moves where each move is counted moving a block by one cell orthogonally.

> [image: Puzzle solution]

Comment: Can you provide the code @FreddyFlares

Comment: @calculatormathematical I dug this code out of the archives from many years ago and its very bloated and unintuitive compared to how I would rewrite it today and it locks up the UI while solving. I also hard hard-coded the immovable block specifically for this problem. Anyway the repo is on github https://github.com/FreddyFlares/SlidingBlock.